# analytics multiplied on seconday dimension

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

Enhanced Ecommerce tracking with Universal Analytics and GTM has been implemented to a site. 
AddToCart,
ProductDetailView,
CheckoutFunnel,
PurchaseTracking,
etc

In the checkout there are 5 steps for the customer to navigate. An checkout event is populated to the dataLayer for each step.

```
'dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'AUD',
    'checkout': {
      'actionField': {
        'step': 2,
        'affiliation': 'AU - Store'
      },
      'products': [{
        'id' : 'productID',
        'name': 'productName',
        'price': '10',
        'quantity': 1
      }]
    }
  }
})'
```

and updated with the checkout option as an event call back when progressing to the next step for payment/shipping option when selected.

```
'dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkoutOption',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'AUD',
    'checkout_option': {
      'actionField': {
        'step': 2,
        'affiliation': 'AU - Store',
        'option': 'PAYPAL'
      }
    }
  }
})'
```

Finally on the last step of the checkout the purchaseTracking populates the dataLayer.

```
'dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'checkout',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'AUD',
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '12345678',
        'revenue': '20',
        'tax': '2',
        'shipping': '10',
        'affiliation': 'AU - Store'
      },
      'products': [{
        'id' : 'productID',
        'name': 'productName',
        'price': '10',
        'quantity': 1
      }]
    }
  }
})'
```

All the transactional data enters GA and updates the Ecommerce Shopping Analysis/Product Performance/Sales Performance views however when viewing product performance and adding 'Checkout Options' as a secondary dimension strange results are shown. It appears that GA is multiplying the sales figures by an arbitrary number once the secondary dimension is added to the report. These results do not occur for any other secondary option that is added to the report, just checkout options

Images for clarity:

[Vanilla product detail report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeGPa.png)

[Product detail report with secondary dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJjL4.png)

Note that the data relative to the checkout option appears correct however the (not set) field has skewed sales performance data. Additionally when no checkout steps are posted though out the checkout and viewed in GA the same results occur with skewed figures against the (not set) line.

I have ensured that the event call back is only posting the data to GA once and all other events are in the dataLater on page load. I cant seem to find any information around this issue anywhere. 
A point into the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers